# failed to print complicated number pattern using c

Tags: c

```
    1
   232
  34543
 4567654
567898765
```

i am trying to write a c program for developing a number pattern shown in the above.
  this is the code what i write for developing the same but it fails it show wrong answer

```
    main()
    {
          int n, c, d, num = 1, space;

          scanf("%d",&n);

          space = n - 1;

          for ( d = 1 ; d <= n ; d++ )
          {
              num = d;

              for ( c = 1 ; c < space ; c++ )
                  printf(" ");

              space--;

              for ( d = 1 ; c <= d ; c++ )
              {
                  printf("%d", num);
                  num++;
              }
              num--;

              for ( c = 1 ; c <= d ; c++)
              {
                  printf("%d", num);
                  num--;
              }
              printf("\n");

          }

          return 0;
    }
```

is my code has any error ? can anybody help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First things first, your *outer* loop uses `d` as the control variable and your second inner loop re-sets it to `1`:

```
for ( d = 1 ; d <= n ; d++ )
    :
    for ( d = 1 ; c <= d ; c++ )
```

The inner loop should be using `c` rather than `d`. Once you fix that, you get something a bit closer:

```
   11
  2332
 345543
45677654
5678998765
```

You can see from that the *middle* digit is being printed one too many times and you can fix that by adjusting the third inner loop to start one value lower (keep in mind the three inner loops are for the leading spaces, the count-up and the count-down):

```
num--;                       // one value lower
for ( c = 1 ; c < d ; c++)   // one less time (< instead of <=)
```

With *that* change, you finally have all the digits right, but the spacing just needs a bit of work:

```
   1
  232
 34543
4567654
567898765
```

And that is a simple matter of adjusting the first inner loop:

```
for ( c = 0 ; c < space ; c++ )  // start at zero rather than one
```

With *all* those changes (and a temporary change to use a constant `5` rather than user input), we end up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int n, c, d, num = 1, space;

    n = 5; // scanf ("%d",&n);

    space = n - 1;

    for (d = 1; d <= n; d++) {
        num = d;

        for (c = 0; c < space; c++ )
            printf (" ");

        space--;

        for (c = 1; c <= d; c++ ) {
            printf ("%d", num);
            num++;
        }
        num--;

        num--;
        for (c = 1; c < d; c++) {
            printf ("%d", num);
            num--;
        }
        printf ("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And we end up with:

```
    1
   232
  34543
 4567654
567898765
```

as desired.

---

Of course, there are more succinct ways of doing this if you just think about the starting and ending conditions of each of the three inner loops, as evidenced here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int numLines;

    numLines = 5;

    for (int line = 1; line <= numLines; line++) {
        // Spaces at start of line.

        for (int spaces = 0; spaces < numLines - line; spaces++)
            putchar (' ');

        // Ascending digits.

        for (int digit = line; digit < line * 2; digit++)
            printf ("%d", digit);

        // Descending digits and newline.

        for (int digit = line * 2 - 2; digit >= line; digit--)
            printf ("%d", digit);

        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()  
{int k=1; 
int num;
scanf("%d",&num);
int x=num;
for(int i=1;i<num+1;i++)
{
int j=i; 
int h;
for(int g=1;g<x;g++)
{
        printf(" ");
}

    while(j!=0){
    printf("%d",k);

    k++;
    j--;
     }
   h=k-1;

   while(h!=i)
{
   printf("%d",k-2);
   k--;
   h--; 
    }    
     k=i+1;
    printf("\n");
    x--;

}   
}
```

Comment: This might help you. first while loop for spacing (-- on every iteration). second loop for printing up to middle element. the last loop for printing the rest elements in (-- order)